# Cyclic codes: greatest common divisor of the generator polynomial and $x^n-1$

Tags: polynomials, coding-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Let's say I have the cyclic code $<z(x)>$ for some polynomial $z(x)$, and it's generator polynomial is $g(x)$. How can I prove that $g(x)$ is the greatest common divisor of $z(x)$ and of $x^n-1$?

Comment: I think that if you read carefully the part under "Algebraic structure" in here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_code, you'll get an answer to your question.

Comment: Could you please clarify? @uniquesolution

Comment: Clarify what? I didn't say anything. You want me to clarify a wiki entry?

Comment: I looked at the wiki entry and I still don't see what you mean...

Comment: You spent about 2 minutes looking there. Give it some more time.

Comment: I know from that that it is a divisor, but I can't see how it shows that its the biggest one. I tried to research it before asking and I have seen this wiki page

Answer (score 1):

Because the ring $\Bbb{F}_q[x]$ is a principal ideal domain, the ideal $I=\langle z(x), x^n-1\rangle$ is actually principal, and generated by 
$d(x)=\gcd(z(x),x^n-1)$. Furthermore, Euclid's algorithm for computing that gcd
actually produces the lowest degree non-zero polynomial in $I$. You may have seen this result in the context of ideals of $\Bbb{Z}$. It is a part of [Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_identity).

Anyway, when we view $I$ as a cyclic code, the lowest degree non-zero polynomial (unique up to a non-zero scalar factor so literally unique in the common case $q=2$) is the generator of the cyclic code. See e.g. chapter 7 of MacWilliams and Sloane. All this is kinda implicit in thar chapter and the following one.

Comment: Not sure about your background, so I am also expecting follow-up questions to be able to edit the answer to a helpful one.